# Jammy kernel 5.19.0-32 breaks amdgpu

Tags: kernel, amdgpu

I run my AMD Kaveri htpc computer with the system provided amdgpu driver on fully updated Jammy. It recently pulled kernel 5.19.0-32 and amdgpu kernel could not load. From dmesg:

```
[    7.619095] amdgpu: Move buffer fallback to memcpy unavailable
[    7.619111] [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* sw_init of IP block <uvd_v4_2> failed -19
[    7.619626] amdgpu 0000:00:01.0: amdgpu: amdgpu_device_ip_init failed
[    7.619632] amdgpu 0000:00:01.0: amdgpu: Fatal error during GPU init
[    7.619637] amdgpu 0000:00:01.0: amdgpu: amdgpu: finishing device.
```

I reverted to kernel 5.15.0-60 and all works fine.

Are there workarounds for Ubuntu 5.19 kernel or bugs filed for this amdgpu error so I can fix or track when it is fixed. I would rather not sit on an older kernel if possible. My searching for answers was inconclusive.

Comment: Have you considered just sticking to the GA kernel stack (ie. 5.15 or the GA kernel which is supported for the life of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS being the default kernel stack for some ISOs too; esp. server).  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: 5.19 was pulled during fresh install. Maybe I have a wrong ppa enabled? I would be happy to stick with GA kernel.

Comment: With Ubuntu, the ISO you use for install sets the default kernel stack (ie. which 22.04 ISO you download/use as many are available) though some server media allows you to select kernel stack at install time, but desktop ISOs are set by the ISO downloaded and used.

Comment: I installed `linux-generic` and removed `linux-generic-hwe-22.04` as well as the offending kernel. I read this will keep me on the 5.15 kernels. But I am still curious why a broken hwe kernel is shipped and how to resolve or track the issue.

Comment: FYI:  You can have both GA & HWE kernel stacks installed; ie. if the HWE kernel stack *regression* you experienced is corrected its easy for you to try (*by just selecting it instead of a GA kernel at grub*). The instructions I gave suggested you *test* with both stacks (GA + HWE) installed first before removing the other (*you just don't remove the other stack*). Some closed-source kernel modules by 3rd parties (nvidia etc) can prevent both stacks co-existing, but also some newer hardware can benefit from the HWE stack.

Comment: The 5.19 kernel has been available for some months now (*in testing but also through 22.10*) but as most users stick to LTS releases it may not have been tested & bugs reported with your exact hardware combination until now; until bug reports are filed the developers cannot know about issues & thus work on them.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: I experience the same problem on my AMD laptop. So I stick with 5.15 kernel, install AMDGPU, and then install Linux Kernel v6.1 using mainline kernel installer.

I am happy with the current config.

Comment: I experienced this same problem, and reported it on the bug reporting system a week ago. Anyone experiencing this please go add to the existing bug report that it also affects you (the more people that do this, the more priority it should get from devs):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2007633

Comment: I have added a comment to your bug @JeffFromOhio. Thank you for opening the bug. Also thanks for the great info guiverc.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved in the recent 6.x hwe kernel.